# I can't understand the alse scope function in kotlin with is not extension function

Tags: function, kotlin, scope

I search for documents, There is a sentence in the document。
scope function 'run' can use called without the context object in not extension function.
I do not find the example in documents. Who can give an example of how to use it。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7R65.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure about your question. Can you try to clarify it please ? Also, try to avoid posting images of text. Instead, copy-paste related text (in quotes, for example), and take time to properly phrase/format your question.

Comment: Try one of the many articles on the Internet, like this one: https://typealias.com/start/kotlin-scopes-and-scope-functions/

Comment: The "context object" is essentially the `Example` in `Example.nameOfExtensionFunction()` (this is also known as a "receiver"). There are [2 variants of `run`, where their usages are documented in the Kotlin docs on scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run) (where one can take a receiver, and you can then do whatever you want with the receiver instance and return it, while the other allows you to execute multiple statements and still return a result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run` without a receiver is used to run a block of code and return an output when you are within a top level (outside of any class) function or property initializer. For example:

```
// At top level, outside of any classes:
val foo = run {
    // some multi-step code to produce output
    theOutput // return the value that will be assigned as the initial value of foo
}
```

The existence of this overload means that `run` can be called from anywhere inside or outside of any class. When you are inside a class and use a bare `run` call without specifying a receiver, there is an implicit `this.` preceding it, so it behaves just like the overload of `run` that has no receiver. When you are outside a class, there isn’t an implicit `this.`, but you can use this other overload of `run` in the same sort of way.